# custom array of images is not working with a simple slider

Tags: jquery, arrays, slider

Im working with wordpress and this is my code for an image that is located in the right sidebar

```
<?php
            $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
            $my_custom_field_img = $custom_fields['sidebarimage'];
            $my_custom_field_desc = $custom_fields['imagedesc'];
            $results = count($my_custom_field_img);
            $i=0;

            if ($my_custom_field_img != null) { ?>
                <div id="right-sidebar">
                    <?php while($i<$results){ ?>
                            <div id="rightimagediv" class="imagediv">
                        <a href="<?php echo $my_custom_field_img[$i]; ?>" rel="testing"><img  id="rightimage" src="<?php echo $my_custom_field_img[$i]; ?>" width="217px" height="150" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <?php if($mycustom_field_desc[$i] != null)?>
                            <span id="imagetext"><?php echo $my_custom_field_desc[$i]; ?></span>                            
                    <?php $i++; } ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

and this is the simple slideshow i used from JonRaasch's blog

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#rightimagediv IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#rightimagediv IMG:last');

// use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#rightimagediv IMG:first');

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

    $(function() {
        setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
    });
```

It works, the images are on top of each other but the thing is when it fades out it keeps going back to the first image.. any help would be gladly appreciated.. Thanx in advance!:)

here's the css:

```
#rightimagediv .imagediv{
        position:relative;
        height:150px;
        }

        #rightimagediv img{
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        z-index:8;
        }

        #rightimagediv img.active {
        z-index:10;
        }

        #rightimagediv img.last-active {
        z-index:9;
        }
```

Comment: Is there any CSS with this? It looks as if $next will always be behind the opaque $active. If there's not you need to add a fade-out to $active

Answer (score 0):

It's because all your images are individually wrapped in link tags, so have no siblings. You can either re-write for `<a>` tags instead of `<img>` or you might be able to do a buggy patch:

```
var $next =  $active.parent().next().children().length ? $active.parent().next().children() : $('#rightimagediv IMG:first');
```

But that relies on each link only having one child and a few other things...

Comment: it is still not working:( im thinking if i should set the first array to be the first image manually something like img: first [1] is that even possible?